# Invoke-RestMethod with spaces in vm name

Tags: powershell, influxdb

I have a VM called "myannoyingVM1 1"

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Post -Body "vms,vmid=VirtualMachine-vm- 
679,vmname=myannoyingvm1 1 cpu=4,memoryGB=8"
```

When I try to post this to my influxdb I get the below...

```
     Invoke-RestMethod : {"error":"unable to parse 'vms,vmid=VirtualMachine-vm-679,vmname=myannoyingvm1 1 cpu=4,memoryGB=8':
invalid field format"}
```

Which makes sense, how do I make it realise that it is one tag

Comment: There's a `,` missing before `cpu`, which may be (part of) the problem.

Comment: In addition of @mklement0 's comment, try : vmname=` myannoyingvm1 1 `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing around with escape characters for curl on Windows OS I found \ works.

$b = "vms3,vmid=VirtualMachine-vm-679,vmname=myannoyingvm1\ 1 cpu=4,memoryGB=8"
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Post -Body $b